# How can I call method of Fragment instance in application context?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

There is a Fragment class defined like `Camera2BasicFragment` in [this project](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2basic/Camera2BasicFragment.java#L74).

I want to call the `takePicture` method in my application, when I received some callbacks in that:

```
public class CameraApplication  extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        public MyCallback mCallback = new MyCallback() {
            public void onRegistered() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    xxx();
                }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried make a new instance of `Camera2BasicFragment` in `onRegistered` method, but it crashed the app, raises

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.hardware.camera2.CaptureRequest$Builder.set(android.hardware.camera2.CaptureRequest$Key, java.lang.Object)'

How can I call method of Fragment instance in application context?

or there is a way to trigger a button of `Camera2BasicFragment`?

Comment: "How can I call method of Fragment instance in application context?" -- you can't. Fragments are only for use by activities. From that `Application`, you do not even know if the activity exists, let alone the fragment.

Comment: Why are you trying to call a fragment method in the application class onCreate? If you truly want to take a photo when you start up the app, then call the capture method in the onCreate of the fragment and have that in the launcher activity.

Comment: @NicRobertson I want to take a photo when I receive a push message, the `dealWithCustomMessage` must be rewritten in application onCreate.

Comment: Why not use the push message handler to start the `CaptureImageActivity`, or have some kind of subscriber based system like http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/